# Como sumar tabla en php?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, tengo un codigo que me carga una tabla de la bd, lo que busco es aprovechar el ciclo para poder sumar y enviarlo en un input.

```
  <table class="table table-striped"> 
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="100">ID</th>
                <th width="250">Codigo</th>
                <th width="200">Item</th>
                <th width="200">Precio</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <!-- Generamos el listado vaciando las variables de la consulta en la tabla -->
              <?php 
              while($persona = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) //Creamos un array asociativo con fetch_assoc 
               //$precio_venta=$persona["precio"];
              { 
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['codigo']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['item']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['precio']; ?></td>
                </tr>

              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *lo que busco es aprovechar el ciclo para poder sumar y enviarlo en un input* **¿Sumar qué?**

Comment: En tu ciclo puedes colocar algo asi: $sumador_total += $persona['precio']; Que supongo que eso es lo que quieres sumar

Comment: Para sumar la columna de dice precio

Comment: justo donde podria ubicar esa instruccion?

Comment: Como ha dicho @LuisFernando. Colocas algo así antes del `while`:  **`$total=0;`**  Dentro del `while` esto:  **`$total += $persona['precio'];`**  y podrás usar `$total` en cualquier parte, al salir del bucle `while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <table class="table table-striped"> 
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="100">ID</th>
                <th width="250">Codigo</th>
                <th width="200">Item</th>
                <th width="200">Precio</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <!-- Generamos el listado vaciando las variables de la consulta en la tabla -->
              <?php 
             $precio_venta =0;
              while($persona = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) //Creamos un array asociativo con fetch_assoc 
               $precio_venta += $persona["precio"];   //justamente aqui y luego puedes hacer un echo $precio_venta;
              { 
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['codigo']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['item']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['precio']; ?></td>
                </tr>

              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Debes inicializar `$precio_venta=0;` antes del `while`, si no, podrías tener datos erróneos o al menos un Warning en la primera ocurrencia del `while`.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregi @A.Cedano

Comment: Gracias a todos funciono.